# How to enforce developers to update validation methods?

Tags: java

I have a peculiar requirement. I have following two methods:

```
public void doSomething(String[] message){

    message[0] = "1";
}

public void validateDoSomething(String[] message){
    if(!"1".equals(message[0])){
        System.out.println("message[0] must be 1");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have two methods `doSomething()` and `validateDoSomething()`. The latter methods serving as validation to former method. The idea here is to use `validateDoSomething()` in unit testing and other validation driven framework.

The issue we are having with this approach is when a new line of code is added to `doSomething()` methods say `message[2] = "2"`, how do we ensure its equivalent `validateDoSomething()` methods is also updated? Further, if something is changed instead of adding like `message[0] = '23'` how to make sure `validateDoSomething()` also reflects this?

We can solve this using process approach where we document and make sure any developer updating `doSomething` also updates its equivalent validate method. But is there a technology solution to this problem? Are there any tools available to make sure developer is forced to update validate method as well?

Comment: You could use a `List<String>` instead and write a test checking the size to be 1. This why your test would fail when another message is added and the person is reminded to update the test.

Answer (score 1):

This is why code reviews are important.  If you set standards like this in your project, you need to have code reviewed by a peer to check for things like this before you can call a task done.

If something is easy to forget, implement policy that makes 2 developers have to forget it.